# Specifically prevent unawarded bounty from going to unsatisfactory answers

Tags: discussion, bounties

I recently put a bounty on a question regarding the [NASA logo](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5739/what-constellation-is-on-the-nasa-logo). I did this as the only two answers on that page are not satisfactory and I wish to encourage a tractable answer.

I am concerned that when the bounty period expires, if I do not select an answer for the bounty that it may be awarded automatically to one of these speculative and unsatisfactory answers. How might I prevent that? I *could* put an answer of my own stating "no satisfactory sources are available" and award the bounty to that, however I feel that there should be a better way.

I stress that I put the bounty on the question specifically because the current answers are not satisfactory and I do **not** want to award them.

Comment: I resolved this myself through two methods. 1.) I answered my own question and marked as the answer. 2.) I never use the bounty system because it doesn't help.

Comment: @Paul: I like to put bounties on other peoples' questions because I see that it does help resolve long-standing questions, especially in the smaller SE sites which may have had smaller membership when the question was asked.

Comment: I'm glad it works for someone. Being I only gain rep by asking questions, giving up whatever additional privileges I may have gained for, well, nothing at all, isn't worth it to me.

Comment: I really like @Paul's idea of answering "No satisfactory answers

Comment: Note that while the bounty will never be auto-awarded to an existing answer (as indicated in the answers here), there's not much you can do to prevent a bounty from being auto-awarded to a *new* unsatisfactory answer.  We need a "no award" option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Automatic awarding only ever applies to answers posted **after** you started the bounty.

The two answers that are already there are not eligible, since they have been posted before your hypothetical bounty. There is no need to worry that they might be awarded the bounty automatically.

Quoting from [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded *half* the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started

Note that you cannot ever award a bounty to your own answer; you cannot use this to prevent an automatic bounty award even if a newer answer was posted with enough upvotes to qualify for automatic awarding.

Answer (score 3):

The bounty will only be auto-awarded to answers given after the bounty was placed, so no worries.

Also, you can't give a bounty to your own answer.

You can read [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for more information.

Comment: I see, thank you. I am still of the opinion that the bounty giver should be able to disregard certain answers (even if given after the bounty period starts). I'll put up a feature request.

Comment: @dotancohen Make sure to search for previous requests before you put in your own request. Also, whether or not this has been asked before, I'm inclined to think such a request won't be well received.

Comment: @Louis: Yes, I was thinking that downvoting an answer should prevent the bounty from being automatically rewarded to that answer, but the truth is that the answers I was concerned with do _not_ deserve a downvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In short: you can't directly prevent the bounty from being auto awarded to an answer that satisfy the conditions i.e. posted after bounty started and has score of at least 2 when the bounty ends.

However, you can try some indirect actions:

1. Comment on the answer, explaining why you think it's not satisfying and asking its author nicely to remove it, or of course to improve it.
2. Downvote the answer. This will cause that extra upvote will be needed to auto award it. This should be done only if the answer is bad to begin with.